# Struct with pointer to struct inside: how to write/read to binary file by a single execution of fwrite/fread

Tags: c, pointers, struct, fwrite, fread

EDIT: This can be done by a single execution of fwrite/fread to the nested pointer to struct, as follows:

```
//write
Path_pointer c;
c.point = (Point*) calloc(2, sizeof(Point));
c.point[0] = (Point){3, 5};
c.point[1] = (Point){-2, 7};
FILE * f = fopen("binary.txt", "wb");
if(f == NULL)  exit(1);
fwrite(c.point, 2*sizeof(Point), 1, f);
fclose(f);

//read
Path_pointer d;
FILE * f = fopen("binary.txt", "rb");
if (f == NULL)  exit(1);
d.point = (Point*) calloc(2, sizeof(Point));
fread(d.point, 2*sizeof(Point), 1, f);
printf("point[0]=(%d,%d)\n", d.point[0].x, d.point[0].y);
printf("point[0]=(%d,%d)\n", d.point[1].x, d.point[1].y);
fclose(f);
```

I have posted this question because it is different from [using pointers in structures to read from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20845119/using-pointers-in-structures-to-read-from-file) and [Writing and reading (fwrite - fread) structures with pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601816/writing-and-reading-fwrite-fread-structures-with-pointers) since:

- it includes dynamic memory allocation (and in this case the question appears what to put as the second parameter of fwrite and fread).
- the aforementioned questions did not receive a proper answer with fwrite() and fread() functions.
- A way to write (using fwrite) to a binary file a struct with a pointer to struct inside, and to read it (using fread) is to do it element by element. My main question is how to write/read such a struct by a single execution of fwrite/fread. This answer cannot be found anywhere in stackoverflow, neither in the two aforementioned posts, nor in any other post.

---

### Original question:

The case with array of struct Point works fine (Path_array), whereas the case with pointer to struct Point does not work (Path_pointer). Perhaps the problem is at the second parameter of functions fwrite() and fread() (i.e., "2*sizeof(Point)").

If I want to write/read a struct like Path_pointer to a binary file, which is the proper way to do it, preferably by a single execution of fwrite/fread?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct  {
    int x, y;
}Point;

typedef struct  {
    Point point[2];
}Path_array;

typedef struct  {
    Point *point;
}Path_pointer;

FILE * f;

int main()  {

    //--- first case: array of struct Point in Path_array ---
    
    //part 1
    Path_array a;
    a.point[0] = (Point){3, 5};
    a.point[1] = (Point){-2, 7};
    f = fopen("binary_array.dat", "wb");
    if(f == NULL)  exit(1);
    fwrite(&a, sizeof(a), 1, f);
    fclose(f);
    
    //part 2
    Path_array b;
    f = fopen("binary_array.dat", "rb");
    if (f == NULL)  exit(1);
    fread(&b, sizeof(b), 1, f);
    printf("point[0]=(%d,%d)", b.point[0].x, b.point[0].y);
    printf(" and point[1]=(%d,%d)\n",b.point[1].x, b.point[1].y);
    fclose(f);
    
    
    //--- second case: pointer to struct Point in Path_pointer ---
    
    //part 3
    Path_pointer c;
    c.point = (Point*) calloc(2, sizeof(Point));
    c.point[0] = (Point){3, 5};
    c.point[1] = (Point){-2, 7};
    f = fopen("binary_pointer.dat", "wb");
    if(f == NULL)  exit(1);
    fwrite(&c, 2*sizeof(Point), 1, f);
    fclose(f);

    
    //part 4
    Path_pointer d;
    d.point = (Point*) calloc(2, sizeof(Point));
    f = fopen("binary_pointer.dat", "rb");
    if (f == NULL)  exit(1);
    fread(&d, 2*sizeof(Point), 1, f);
    printf("point[0]=(%d,%d)", d.point[0].x, d.point[0].y);
    printf(" and point[1]=(%d,%d)\n",d.point[1].x, d.point[1].y);
    fclose(f);
    
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't save pointers in a file because the next time the program runs, the memory layout may be different, which will make the pointers invalid. That's almost certainly the case with [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization). It can also be the case if you make even the slightest change to the program.

Comment: *My main question is how to write/read such a struct by a single execution of fwrite/fread. This answer cannot be found anywhere in stackoverflow, neither in the two aforementioned posts, nor in any other post.*  That's because it simply can not exist.  All C read/write operations read or write contiguous chunks of memory.  A pointer in the midst of such a chunk **refers to another chunk**.  You're looking for an answer to prove 2+2 = 5.  You won't find one.

Comment: There is an asnwer: It can be done by a single execution of fwrite/fread to the nested pointer to struct. I have edited the question to include the relevant code.

Comment: The latest code that you posted **does not** store pointers in the file. If you look at the file with a hex editor, you'll see that it contains `03 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 fe ff ff ff 07 00 00 00`. In other words, it contains the numbers `3, 5, -2, 7`. Those are the values of the two points. It's exactly the same file that the "part1" code creates.

Comment: You can store the struct with a single `fwrite` because it contains a single pointer, to  a single block of memory, that contains all of the data. As soon as you add anything else to the structure, the single `fwrite` won't be possible anymore, [as discussed in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56149988).

Comment: @user3386109 You are right on this

Answer (score 2):

you need to think what this :

```
typedef struct  {
   Point *point;
}Path_pointer;
```

looks like in memory. The member `point` contains a pointer, it does not contain a `Point`. When you write it to a file you are writing a memory address only.

You should start by deciding what you want to data layout in the file to be (generally dumping raw structs toa file is a bad idea). Then write code that write data that way.

NOTE. you are calling the files `.txt` even though they are not text, it doesnt change the behaviors (the file can be called "an_elehpant_lives.in_my_trousers" if you like) but it will surely confuse people,